# Set radio button default in Angular - TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a radio button group which I'm trying to set a default value of 2 but I  am getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ratingradio' of undefined'

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="RadioController"> 
    <label for="commentstarrating" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Rating</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label><input type="radio" name="ratingradio" value="1" ng-model="feedback.ratingradio">1</label>
    </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
           <label><input type="radio" name="ratingradio" value="2" ng-model="feedback.ratingradio">2</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and some javascript in a separate file

```
.controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.feedback.ratingradio=2;
            console.log($scope.feedback.ratingradio);
 //redacted the function for brevity
```

Error is thrown at

```
        $scope.feedback.ratingradio=2;
```

and the console shows the same

```
        console.log($scope.feedback.ratingradio);
```

I can't understand because if I select a value then submit my form, the radio button value should be assigned to JSON object I will send to the server. Once I get this fix of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$scope.feedback.ratingradio=2;
```

to

```
$scope.feedback = {
  ratingradio:2
};
```

Comment: This worked and my problem is now fixed. Many thanks, you've made my day!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can define  `$scope.feedback.ratingradio=2` in your angular. Can you just define `$scope.feedback=2` instead? That will work. Obviously you'll need `ng-model="feedback"`

Comment: This is also great. Thanks to you too.

Answer (score 0):

First thing here is controller used in html and in Java Script are different.
Second thing is ng-model, you are using the same name for two different field.

For your information :

The role of controllers in Angular is to expose data to our view via $scope, and to add functions to $scope that contain business logic to enhance view behavior.

Also With the ng-model directive you can bind the value of an input field to a variable created in AngularJS.

Reference Link : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: I neglected to mention that RadioController was a child of DishCommentController. Thanks for the response.